# Is there a unique adjective describing someone who always sleeps soundly?

Tags: word-request

I'm curious to find a word for those who sleep "like a log", very deeply. Those who once asleep are very difficult to wake.

For example in all Iranian languages, there is an expression which translates literally as:

> My sleep is heavy.
>
> His sleep is very heavy.
>
> How heavy your sleep is!

In addition, I already found an adjective **(sound asleep)** which is very rare to use.

Comment: It's probably true to say that ***sound** asleep* is becoming a (very) little dated/literary by comparison with ***fast** asleep*, but [they're both still perfectly common, not "very rare"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=He+was+sound+asleep%2CHe+was+fast+asleep%2C&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CHe%20was%20sound%20asleep%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CHe%20was%20fast%20asleep%3B%2Cc0) We usually apply ***heavy*** to the person rather than the activity, so a ***heavy sleeper*** is likely to be ***fast asleep***.

Comment: How do you use it? Is it ok to say: I'm fast sleep (to mean I always sleep very deeply). @FumbleFingers

Comment: In English, this person would be known as a **heavy sleeper**

Comment: @Yazdan Samiei Poor: Haha - NO! It's almost impossible to imagine a context where you could say *I'm fast asleep*, since being fast asleep is a  *temporary* state during which it's not normally possible to speak under conscious / voluntary control. Note that *I'm a heavy sleeper* [is edging out](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I%27m+a+heavy+sleeper%2CI%27m+a+sound+sleeper&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20%27m%20a%20heavy%20sleeper%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20%27m%20a%20sound%20sleeper%3B%2Cc0) *I'm a sound sleeper* over recent decades.

Comment: Thank you mike, that's the right answer. so you use the same concept as Iranian language speakers do. Interesting :) @mike

Comment: @YazdanSamieiPoor: Apparently so :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers sorry to make a funny sentence. LOL. You've got such a right to laugh at me. :) ;) :)

Comment: @Yazdan Samiei Poor: I'd like to think I was laughing ***with*** you, not ***at*** you. That's to say I was hoping that you would *also* laugh once you'd understood the implications of the"definition" I followed up with (which I specifically included because I guessed you might not appreciate why it was funny if I didn't explain *exactly* what "fast asleep" means, and how it's used).

Comment: The adjective that you are looking for is "lucky".

Comment: @FumbleFingers Surely you are right. I'm completely ok with it. It doesn't matter at all.on the contrary you made me happy my brother.

Comment: Where I come from (eastern part of the US) **sound asleep** is definitely in use, and I have no sense that its use is on the wane.  It doesn't mean that the person *usually* falls into a deep sleep as *he is a heavy sleeper* does;  *to be sound asleep* means to be in a deep sleep.

Comment: @TRomano: I never thought about possible US/UK differences when I posted that. Turns out that although ***sound** asleep* has always been a minority usage in [BrE](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=was+sound+asleep%2Cwas+fast+asleep&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwas%20sound%20asleep%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwas%20fast%20asleep%3B%2Cc0), it's now actually the *dominant* form in AmE. At least, the *written* instances in Google Books. Still sounds a (teeny) bit "quaint, folksy" to me as a Brit (but it's a very fine metaphoric distinction).

Comment: @Yazdan: We're all brothers (except the sisters, with whom we are congenitally conjoined in [siblinghood](http://www.yourdictionary.com/siblinghood)). My only regret is that I felt obliged to write ***whom*** there because we're on a website aimed at people who want to learn English. But rest assured, my friend - if we were talking over a cup of coffee, I'd almost certainly have said ***who***. There's what people who teach English *say* you should say, and there's what people who speak English *actually* say.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the comments, "sound sleeper" or "heavy sleeper" are both used, specifically in the context of [someone who doesn't wake up easily](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/heavy-sleeper).

> My roommate came home late last night and started practicing the drums, but I'm such a heavy sleeper I didn't hear a thing.

"I slept like a log" is the most common idiomatic expression, but usually when you have a deep and *restful* sleep.

> My new bed is so comfortable, I slept like a log!

Comment: Until about a century ago, [**slept like a top** was more common than **slept like a log**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=slept+like+a+log%2Cslept+like+a+top&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cslept%20like%20a%20log%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cslept%20like%20a%20top%3B%2Cc0). The former still occurs, but it's a bit dated today, and mainly restricted to older people and literary contexts.

Comment: Why "like a top"?  Did they mean the children's toy that spins and spins?  Doesn't seem like a restful metaphor ...

Comment: Your guess would have been as good as mine at the time when we wrote our comments above, but [this website](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/sleep-like-a-top.html) says *When a top is spinning well the precessional effect causes its axis to remain stationary and it can appear to be still, that is, 'sleeping'* (where I'm guessing at least *some* visitors here will need to look up ***precessional**!* :)